# nodejs : how to compile grpc with newer openssl?

Tags: node.js, openssl, grpc

I would like to compile grpc with newer openssl( >= 1.1.0 ) in nodejs project, but I have no idea how to get along with it.

Here is the `package.json` in the whole project.

```
{
    "name": "fabcar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "FabCar application implemented in JavaScript",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8",
        "npm": ">=5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "pretest": "npm run lint",
        "test": "nyc mocha --recursive"
    },
    "engineStrict": true,
    "author": "Hyperledger",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric-ca-client": "~1.4.0",
        "fabric-network": "~1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint": "^5.9.0",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0",
        "nyc": "^13.1.0",
        "sinon": "^7.1.1",
        "sinon-chai": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "nyc": {
        "exclude": [
            "coverage/**",
            "test/**"
        ],
        "reporter": [
            "text-summary",
            "html"
        ],
        "all": true,
        "check-coverage": true,
        "statements": 100,
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100
    }
}
```

And in this project, the `fabrc-ca-client`, `fabric-network` will uses `grpc`.

here is some env:

```sh
$ npm version

{ npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '32.0',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '60.1',
  modules: '57',
  napi: '4',
  nghttp2: '1.33.0',
  node: '8.16.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2r',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '6.2.414.77',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }

$ node -v
v8.16.0
```

Please help on `compile grpc in nodejs with newer openssl(>=1.1.0)`.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and only need to building on linux.

Any advice would be greatful!

Thanks!

Comment: It's using on the gm-modified fabric sdk. 这用于国密 fabric node sdk, 如有已经研究过的大兄弟，还请不吝赐教！多谢！

Comment: Is it possible to replace all the \*.h in `node_modules/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/boringssl/include/openssl`
 with my openssl/lib/*.h ? And then compile. Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three major obstacles to building grpc with a different OpenSSL library. First, Node.js already exports the OpenSSL symbols for native modules to dynamically link against. This means that you won't be able to dynamically link your own OpenSSL library; it would cause symbol collision errors. You would need to statically link the library, and be sure to hide the symbols. This can require either explicitly linking the relevant `.a` file if you already have one, or compiling the library from source as part of the build process. This is not an issue when building for Windows or for Electron, so you should be able to get away with dynamically linking in those cases

Second, the OpenSSL headers are included in the Node headers that are included by default when building native addons like grpc. If you want to use your own version of OpenSSL, you will need to use your own headers for that version instead of those headers. We currently need to do this to use BoringSSL in the Windows library, so we have `node-gyp` download the headers, then we go in and delete the `openssl` directory, then build the library for real. You will likely need to do that in this situation too. This isn't an issue on Electron.

Third, grpc is written to use a variety of specific APIs in OpenSSL. Depending on which other version you want to use, there is a chance that it will not be compatible. I am not sure what the usable version range is here, but this is something to keep in mind.

If you can solve all of these problems, you will need to make some significant edits to grpc's `binding.gyp` file to accomplish this. If you are building OpenSSL from source, the existing `boringssl` target should be a good template. You can add a similar target for `openssl` and then have the `grpc` target depend on it. If you already have a `.a` file, you should be able to add a linker flag to the `grpc` target to link it. In either case, make sure to remove references to other OpenSSL headers in various parts of the file.